# Unterminated &lt;c:if tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm getting an `Unterminated &lt;c:if tag` error. This is my code and I don't think that there is anything missing?

```
<select name="<portlet:namespace /><%=Const.LR_ROLE%>">
    <c:forEach items="${lrRoles}" var="role">
        <c:if test="${role.name != 'user' && role.name != 'User'}">
            <option value="${role.roleId}" <c:if="${role.roleId == 'curLrRoleId'}"> selected="selected" </c:if>> ${role.name}</option>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your `<option>` tag. Attribute `test` is missing.

```
<option value="${role.roleId}" <c:if test="${role.roleId == 'curLrRoleId'}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${role.name}</option>
                                     ^
```